# Unpleasant crust on bread

Tags: baking, bread, crust

I'm baking ~67% hydration bread, following this recipe [Kvali food dutch oven bread.](http://www.kvalifood.com/page/the-world-s-best-bread-no-knead-bread-dutch-oven-bread/uuid/fd1212f3-4f7c-11e6-b497-3a4fdee1ccff)
The bread is baked using a covered cast iron casserole dish heated to 250'c, and following the cooking times suggested in the recipe.

However, the bread is developing a crust that is "sucky" rather than either chewy or crunchy.  It pulls moisture from the mouth and ends up unpleasant to eat - despite having blisters.

This effect gets worse the longer wait to eat the bread - it's bearable straight out of the oven but after an hour or so is a major detractor from the bread experience.

Comment: The link didn't work for me.  And I assume the question would be how to fix the recipe, as there wasn't one specifically stated.  (but I can't see the recipe).  If you could edit the question to add the recipe, they're not considered copyrightable in the US.  (so long as you just stick to the ingredients & steps, and avoid the 'flavor text')

Comment: Thanks Joe,

The link was very slightly off - so this should work now.

Comment: Assuming you _did_ remember to take the lid off for the last stage, @Mark Wildon's answer sounds good - it could well be overproofed.

Answer (score 4):

The recipe specifies a two hour proof after the twelve hour fermentation. Depending on the activity of the yeast and the ambient temperature this might be too long. In overproofed bread the gluten network is fragile and unable to support the loaf through baking. The result is a soggy or dense loaf and crust, consistent with your observation that the crust isn't chewy or crunchy.

Also there are no instructions to slash the loaf before baking. Slashing helps the loaf expand and gives more variety to the crust since some parts are more exposed to the heat of the oven then others.

Finally you mention that the crust is best straight out of the oven. After baking the loaf is still slightly moist: cutting into it immediately will prevent it from drying fully. Again I suspect this leads to a soggy crust.